# How to pass function to client from Node.js server

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js, function

All:

What I want to do is like:

**On Node server side:**

```
var fn = function(){
    alert("hello");
}
```

I want to **send this function to client side**(currently using AngularJS, but it does not matter as long as this problem can be solved), and bind it to a button click event. So I can get pop-out alert window when click that button.

Thanks

Comment: You might be interested in [Socket.io](http://socket.io/).

Comment: You would need the client to request javascript from the node server, the node server would in turn respond with that javascript(as a string), the client would then have to hook it into the click event. I don't quite understand why this function exists at all in node.js if you want to use it in the client. you can't just pass a function from node to the client, you would have to pass it as a string, and then parse it.

Comment: a bad idea would be to do a `fn.toString()`,send it to the client, and eval the string.

Comment: @adeneo Send it just like defining this function on client side and bind it with jQuery

Comment: @JCOC611 Could you give me an example? Thanks

Comment: @Hacketo Yes, I was thinking use [function].toString(), but I do not know how to eval it to a client-side variable, could you give me an example?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? this seems wrong in so many ways..

Comment: You have all the thing to try it. socket.io provide examples, node some learning, look for eval string (or better way). seem too broad question

Comment: @Kevin B The reason is I need to authorize client to dynamically bind function to a button, I do not want to static code it on client side.

Comment: You'll have to static code the code that grabs the function, evals it, and binds it to the element instead, i don't see how that's any different other than being far more complex and harder to maintain.\

Comment: The server can't just magically send this javascript to the client and bind it to an element, the client has to do all(er, most...) of that work.

Comment: @KevinB in this case, he want to send the function, not all binding stuff.

Comment: I interpreted his last comment a bit differently.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, The code grabbing function is for sure coded on client side,   the only part I do not want to code on client side is the click handling function

Comment: Then define it as a string and have the client send an http request to retrieve it, the same way you would request any other string. Still think this function should instead exist on the client to begin with, and then just hit the server to see if the client is authorized to use it. If it's such a protected function, maybe it shouldn't exist on the client at all.

Comment: I agree with @Kevin B that this sounds wrong. Try to think about the problem differently. Maybe what you want is  to authorize the client to some action performed in the on-click function? For example authorize it to receive some response data from the server?

Comment: @Hacketo  I read some tutorials about how JSONP works, I wonder if we can use the way how JSONP works to passing the function to client side?

Comment: jsonp works the same way as including another script on the page does. `var s = document.createElement('script'); s.src = "foo.js"; document.head.appendChild(s);`

Comment: @klode Actually, the function will only work on frontend side once it sent to client, it is like chart drawing function which does not need to communicate with server, If I define all possible chart drawing functions on client side, then the client user will be able to bind any of them to the button which is not what I want, I want to limit what kind of chart drawing function  the client user can use

Comment: Then have the js file that would return the functions for the charts only return the ones that the user is authorized to use. Caching is probably going to be an issue.

Comment: @Kuan the problem of evaluating script is the injection, you want to protect your function, but you're opening a way to execute code. And if someone want to execute his function in the scope defined, he could do what you don't want to happens

Comment: It should be noted that Node is a server like any other, with EJS, Jade etc. you could just output the string in a script tag, without the need to eval anything at all ?

Comment: @adeneo Thanks, that is also a way to do it, just show user different page.

Comment: @Hacketo Ok, so as you and KevinB said, what pattern do you recommend that I should use to do the task I mention above(most important part is limiting what function can user use)?

Comment: @Kuan, do the most part of the job server side and send only the relevant thing to the client as a text shown, see the client side only as an interface/display.

Comment: @Hacketo Ok, it make sense, but I wonder how to do it actually in my case? Suppose I do not send chart drawing function to client, but drawing it on server and send the whole drawing chart HTML to client side? The crucial part is this chart is highly interactive, I just have no idea how to achevie this on server side.

Comment: @Kuan In your case, if you want to enable a feature client side, you should provide the feature directly in the source, you could create a custom javascript code for each user (with some cache when the feature is enabled) or if you have not a lot of features, caching per fonctionnalities

Comment: @Hacketo Thanks, but I am still thinking about authorization thing, how can I disable the those function for unauthorized user if I put function in source?

Comment: In a directive you can bind / show the actions a user has available to them but **all** functions any user could ever do should be sent to the client as mixing and matching source delivered to the client is going to lead to a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Is there some concern that a user would open the browser debugger and then run actions they should not?

Comment: @Enzey  That is exactly what I am concerning...

Comment: That is not the job of the client, that is the job of the server. For example if an action exists in the client code and the user finds it and calls the server should recognize that the user does not have the right to preform the action and ignore the request.

Comment: @Enzey So the correct way to do this is: Add authorization request function as first step for chart drawing function to get authorization then execute the function?

Comment: So the action you are trying to block the user from having access to draws a chart in the browser and there is no interaction to the server, such as CRUD to persisted data?

Comment: @Enzey Yes, in my original design, there is a button which needs to submit the user info to get according drawing function sent from server, then bind to the button, then click the button can make the chart drawn. Current design is binding desired function to button and click will submit request to server for authorization to execute that function

Comment: @Enzey, what I am concerning is in this way though, the client still be able to view the drawing function part, by copying and executing the drawing code part, they can still skip the authorization.

Comment: So what stops a user that does have access from extracting the function sent to them and giving it to another user or posting it online? It sounds like you are trying to lock access to a Javascript function that displays a graph in the browser with data the user already has.

Comment: if you want to protect access to the charting functions, what about keeping the charting function on the server, running it on the server side when an authorized user requests it, and sending to the client the resulting graph as an image?

Answer (score 0):

So, something like this:

```
// Predefined functions
var allowedFunctions = {
    'f1': function () {alert('Called f1');},
    'f2': function () {alert('Called f2');},
    'f3': function () {alert('Called f3');},
};

// This comes from the server
var callThisOne = 'f2';

// Here's how you call it now
allowedFunctions[callThisOne]();
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this way, if I am the user, I still be able to try to get the function body.

Comment: I don't know then. Not quite sure what are your requirements. I gave you two options, considering the information you have provided. If none work, I'm afraid you will have to rethink the design of your app.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/WSJJIA2CWxGXCXCMvfRA?p=preview).

```
// Get this from the server
var textReceived = 'var fn = function(){ alert("hello"); };';

function getFunction(textReceived) {
  eval(textReceived);
  return fn;
}

var f = getFunction(textReceived);

f();
```

Comment: It does not make any sense though, server should send data only. Remember, any eval() is a security risk.

Comment: Thanks for help.  It seems most people disagree on sending functions to client side, so what pattern do you recommend to do this task? It is mentioned in my question post, basically, I want to limit the kind of functions that a user can use to bind

Comment: I would pre-define all allowed functions in the app, so they all are available in the code. On the server side all you do is just send the function name or some sort of id, look the according function up by that id and bind it to the event.