# selenium-webdriver pass an array of functions as argument to executeScript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriverjs

```
import webdriver from 'selenium-webdriver';

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
              .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
              .build();

driver.get('https://www.google.com');
let foo = function(rules) {
  rules.forEach(rule => {
    rule();
  });
}
let bar = function() { return 'bar' };
let baz = function() { return 'baz' };
driver.executeScript(foo, [bar, baz]).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});

driver.quit();
```

it errors out with

```
WebDriverError: unknown error: rule is not a function


let foo = function(rules) {
  return rules;
  // rules.forEach(rule => {
  //   rule();
  // });
}
let bar = function() { return 'bar' };
let baz = function() { return 'baz' };
driver.executeScript(foo, [bar, baz]).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result); // refer the log pasted below
});
```

Looks like the function are being serialized a `string`

```
[ 'function bar() {\n  return \'bar\';\n}',
  'function baz() {\n  return \'baz\';\n}' ]
```

Any pointer on how to pass `array of functions as arguments` would be helpful.

Comment: Have a read of the comments on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117733/how-to-pass-function-to-client-from-node-js-server. Consensus is that approach won't work / doesn't make sense / is wrong. Besides, the WebDriver protocol knows nothing about JavaScript *functions*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a different work around, w/o using `eval` **explicitly**, but in similar fashion.

1. the functions to be injected must be [named
   function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression)
2. inject the `function.toString()` as the content of a `<script>`

   ```
   function foo(rules) {
     var result = [];
     rules.forEach(rule => {
       result.push(rule());
     });
     return result;
   }
   function bar() { return 'bar' };
   function baz() { return 'baz' };

   function inject(content) {
     var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.innerHTML = content;
     document.head.appendChild(script);
   }
   let script = `${bar.toString()} ${baz.toString()} ${foo.toString()}`;

   driver.executeScript(inject, script);
   ```
3. then execute the desired function as

   ```
   driver.executeScript('return foo([bar, baz])').then(function(result) {
     // use the result
   });
   ```

---

complete example

```
// example.js
import webdriver from 'selenium-webdriver';

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
  .build();

driver.get('https://www.google.com');

function foo(rules) {
  var result = [];
  rules.forEach(rule => {
    result.push(rule());
  });
  return result;
}
function bar() { return 'bar' };
function baz() { return 'baz' };

function inject(content) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.innerHTML = content;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}
let script = `${bar.toString()} ${baz.toString()} ${foo.toString()}`;

driver.executeScript(inject, script);

driver.executeScript('return foo([bar, baz])').then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});

driver.quit();
```

---

```
> babel-node example.js

[ 'bar', 'baz' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**:
All non trivial data passed as arguments to function are converted to string because it's the only way to inject something from selenium driver to browser.

> Arguments must be a number, a boolean, a String, WebElement, or a List of any combination of the above.

**Solution**
You can convert string to function and execute it using `eval` or function constructor `new Function('...function body here...')`. Yes, it's a very bad, but actually, there is no other way to pass non trivial data from driver to browser. Actually, when you call this `driver.executeScript(foo, [], ...)`, `foo` function is also converted to string and executed in browser using `eval` too.

If I were you, I would try to to find another way to achieve results without passing functions as arguments.

You can read more at: https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html

Comment: Thanks, I tried with, `eval` and `new Function`, didn't work, most likely I have change the implementation.

Comment: @TimurBilalov You say it's very bad, I'd argue as it's temporary injection and only present on the page in a test environment when it's explicitly injected by WebDriver that it's a perfectly valid strategy for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use eval. See code below:

```
driver.get('https://www.google.com');
let foo = function(rules) {
    var results = [];
    rules.forEach(rule => {
        results.push(eval(rule));
    });
    return results;
}

let bar = "(function() { return ' message returned from bar' })()";
let baz = "(function() { return 'message returned from baz' })()";

driver.executeScript(foo, [bar, baz]).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: `console.log(eval(rule))`, I don't want to log the function but execute it. How to execute it?

Comment: I have tried this. Both bar and baz are executed correctly. Could you try it again?

Comment: for me `null` gets printed, please verify that the code posted and one your are executing are same. BTW, `console.log(eval(rule));` is not returning any values.

Comment: I intend to log it inside browser's console. If you want to get results on cmd or shell, you have to add result of each eval to a list, then return it.

Comment: @sarbbottam I've updated the code to return array of results. Please take a look and let me know if it solve your problem or not.